# How to setup Facebook to grant access to Page data via Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook fan page which exists about 3 years now.
Now I wanted to use it as a content repository for my new homepage (providing information about upcoming events, latest Facebook posts, photo albums).

My problem is not about the usage of the PHP SDK itself - my problem is that I'm completely stuck with setting up access tokens and so on. Actually I'm not even sure what I'm supposed to do.

I already created an app via developers.facebook.com and got the app_id and app_secret. And well, now I'm stuck...

How is my App even related to the Page and where can I set its relation? I guess I must somehow grant access to the page but deny access to other informations such as my private facebook profile or other pages.

My current code looks like this:

```
$facebook = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => $parameters['facebook_app_id'],
    'app_secret' => $parameters['facebook_app_secret'],
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.6'
]);

try {
    $response = $facebook->get('/my-page-id/feed', '{access token}');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

This returns the following error:

> Facebook SDK returned an error: You must provide an access token.

Now, where do I get the correct access token from?
I actually got an access token for the page itself (I guess), via the Graph API Explorer calling "me/accounts". Not only that this felt completely wrong, it now returns the following error:

> Graph returned an error: Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument

What do you want from me now Facebook!?

It would be very helpful if someone could provide a step-by-step guide on how to correctly setup a Facebook page for this basic read-only tasks?

Comment: You need to get a page access token. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: I already did this which led me to > Graph returned an error: Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument

Comment: That’s a security setting you can turn off in app dashboard.